# Split array elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have below scenarios to handle.

```
let data = [
    [ "ALISHA", "SUICA", "PASMO" ],
    [ "HARMONY" ],
    [ "OCTOPUS" ]
]

let data1 = [
    [ "ALISHA",  ],
    [ "HARMONY" ],
    [ "OCTOPUS", "SUICA", "PASMO" ]
]
```

For both of the above data, i want the result to look like this.

```
let result = [
    [ "ALISHA" ],
    [ "HARMONY" ],
    [ "OCTOPUS" ], 
    [ "SUICA" ],
    [ "PASMO" ]
]
```

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this. I tried the following but no success

```
let result = []
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let split = data[i].split(",");  // just split once
    result.push(split[0]); // before the comma 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we will use forEach method on main array inside forEach we will use if condition if is array and length more than 1 will add another forEach method and push sub array to main array after that remove sub array
look like that

```js
let data = [
  ["ALISHA"],
  ["HARMONY"],
  ["OCTOPUS", "SUICA", "PASMO"]
]

data.forEach((cur, index) => {
  if (Array.isArray(cur) && cur.length > 1) {
    cur.forEach(cur => data.push([cur]))
    data.splice(index, 1);
  }
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: we cant use data[2] as it becomes hardcoded. the data can be dynamic. instead of having sub array elements in index number 2, we can have sub array elements in index 1. so in this scenario, your solution would not work

Answer (score 1):

Uses `Array.reduce` extract all elements, then convert to `[string]` by `Array.map`.

```js
const data = [
    [ "ALISHA" ],
    [ "HARMONY" ],
    [ "OCTOPUS", "SUICA", "PASMO" ]
]

console.log(
  data.reduce((pre, cur) => [...pre, ...cur], []).map(item => [item])
  // data.reduce((pre, cur) => pre.concat(...cur), []).map(item => [item]) // different methods but same logic (uses Array.concat instead of spread operator)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = [["ALISHA"], ["HARMONY"], ["OCTOPUS", "SUICA", "PASMO"]];

const result = data.flat().map((a) => [a]);
console.log(result);
```